# Is there any difference between "x" and "&x[0]" in C?

Tags: c, dereference

Going through some piece of software written in C, I encountered the following bit of code, which I can summarize as such:

```
void fill_array_with_some_data(int *_)
{
    // assign some arbitrary int values to _[0] and _[1]
    _[0] = 42;
    _[1] = 24;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x[2] = {0};
    fill_array_with_some_data(&x[0]);
    
    // do something with the data which is now is x
    if (x[0] & 0x42)
        // do something
    
    return 0;
}
```

Seeing `&x[0]` instead of simply `x` seemed odd to me.

Is there any difference between both?

Is there any reason why one would want to use `&x[0]` rather than simply `x`?

Comment: x is shorthand for &x[0]. An array decays to a pointer to its first element when used in an expression.

Comment: In your context, they are the same. One of the few places where they are different is in `sizeof(x)` and `sizeof(&x[0])`. The former gives the total size of the array; the latter gives the size of an `int*`. (Change it to `int x[3]` to be sure to see a different value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `fill_array_with_some_data(&x[0])`, `x` and `&x[0]` are equivalent.

After `int x[2] = {0];`, `x` designates an array. When an array is used in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to its first element except when:

- it is used as the operand of sizeof, as in `sizeof x`,
- it is used as the operand of unary `&`, as in `&x`, or
- it is a string literal used to initialize an array, as in `char s[] = "abc";`.

Thus `sizeof x` will give the size of the array, whereas `sizeof &x[0]` will give the size of a pointer to an element of `x`.

`&x` and `&x[0]` will both point to the same location in memory, but they have different types. `x` has type “pointer to array of 2 `int`, and `&x[0]` has type “pointer to `int`”. This means `&x + 1` will point to after the end of the entire array `x`, but `&x[0] + 1` will point to after the element `x[0]` (so it points to `x[1]`).

Generally, one would write `&x[0]` only when one wants to point specifically to the element. When filling the array with some data, programmers should write `fill_array_with_some_data(x)` to convey they expect the routine to operate on the entire array. This makes no difference to the compiler, but it helps humans understand what is being done. One should use `&x[0]` only to call out that element particularly. For example, if a routine `foo` operates on only one element, we might write `foo(&x[0])` to indicate that to the reader.

Comment: "&x and &x[0] will both point to the same location in memory": you probably mean "x and &x[0]".
I also don't get your point about &x + 1 pointing to after the end of the entire array (indeed, &x is a pointer to pointer to int, hence *(&x + 1) is a pointer to int).

Comment: @Raman: No, my text is correct, `&x` and `&x[0]` point to the same location in memory. And `&x` is not a pointer to a pointer to an `int`; it is a pointer to an array. Arrays are not pointers. If the array `x` is located at address 1000, and `int` objects are four bytes, then the array `x` of 2 `int` will occupy bytes at addresses from 1000 to 1007, inclusive, and the value of `&x + 1` will address 1008.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a code snippet illustrating the behaviour you describe? I can't reproduce it using https://onlinegdb.com/cRtTbGXX9

Comment: @Raman: That program improperly attempts to store 11 after the end of `x`. That breaks the program; the behavior is not defined by the C standard. You are allowed to do arithmetic to move a pointer to just beyond the end of an array (or any object), but you cannot dereference it. To see the difference, simply execute `printf("%p\n", x); printf("%p\n", x+1); printf("%p\n", &x+1);`. The first will print the address where `x` starts. The second will print the address where the next element is. The third will print the address after the end of `x`.

Comment: I see. I was indeed misunderstanding the behaviour of pointers to an array.

Answer (score 2):

There aren’t any differences other than style.

Passing `&x[0]` as an argument may suggest that the programmer only wants the function to access the first element, where passing `x` would imply they expect the function to access the whole array.  But that would be merely conventional, and the code sample given in the question clearly does not even respect this convention.

As far as the language standard is concerned, the expressions are exactly equivalent, at least in evaluated contexts (other than `sizeof`): `&x[0]` is a shorthand for `&*(x + 0)`, which can be simplified to `&*x` and then `x`.